# What is TopSectionListener in this, a keyword?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I perfectly understand that TopSectionListener is a method which is used to connect the activity to the fragment. But why do we unnecessarily introduce activitycommander? What is activityCommander in this?

```
TopSectionListener activityCommander;
 public interface TopSectionListener {
    public void creatememe(String top, String bottom);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: `TopSectionListener` is not a method, it's an interface. And `activityCommander` is a variable of type `TopSectionListener`

Comment: Could you please tell me why do we need a variable of an interface type? What's the use of it? I am quite new to programming so have some basic questions

Answer (score 0):

Below is a better arrangement of the code for understanding:

```
public interface TopSectionListener {
    public void creatememe(String top, String bottom);
}
```

`TopSectionListener activityCommander;`

1. In order to communicate with the Activity (`MainActivity` in this case), an interface `TopSectionListener` and a variable of it `activityCommander` are created;
2. `TopSectionListener` here is then data type (interface) and can be used to declare its own variables like activityCommander.
3. This interface is attached to the activity (MainActivity) where the fragment sits, using `onAttach()`
4. When button is clicked, a method defined in the interface is called;
5. This method is implemented in the MainActivity; MainActivity receives the call and carries out the method (called by the `TopSectionFragment`)